# MultiAutocomplete Textview

Tags: android

In my project i am trying to implement multi `AutoCompleteTextView`. Here what I am trying to do is whenever we are writing anything in that view it will make an API call and show the data in the hint. But whenever I have selected one hint that text will come in that view with comma, so once one item is appeared on the view then next time the API call has to be made by the new search query. But I am unable to do that because there is already one selected item showing in the view so in the search query the whole text is going. That's why no data is coming. Is there any way to do that? Like in Gmail exactly how **cc** is working, I want to achieve that.

Comment: you can substring your search query by comma

Comment: hi @VivekMishra will you explain it little bit

Comment: use the string class substring method to get the string after the comma

Comment: ok sure i will try it ,if i am not able to do it i will come back.

Comment: hi vivek thanks for your valuable suggestion....i have tried a lot previously but not able to get it.....but your solution works thanks again for the help...now i have one another doubt if i am selecting one item from the list shown in multiautocomplete text view then i want to put that text in a box in that view exactly how gmail cc is appearing ......is there any help regarding this...................

Comment: may be this could help https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="AutoCompleteTextView" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="MultiAutoCompleteTextView" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:ems="14"
        android:hint="MultiAutoCompleteTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
String wholeString = "Hello,How are you";
String newData = wholeString.substring(wholeString.lastIndexOf(","));
```

`newData` will return "How are you" so now you can call API with new string.